# Python: Will using open('file.ext', 'rb').read()[4000:4005] load all of the file into memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to open and process some large files in chunks today. For some reason, I can't use a generator. So, if I use

```
open('file.ext', 'rb').read()[4000:4005]
```

will it load all file contents into memory?

Comment: What does the documentation for `read()` say?

Comment: Yes it will. For more efficient reading you can use [`.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek).

Comment: So,`a = open('file.ext', 'rb').seek(4000)`  `a.read(5)` will do the trick  i.e. it will not load all of the file?

Comment: Note that `a = open('file.ext', 'rb').seek(4000)` makes `a` the return value of `seek`, which is the new position in the file (an integer), not the open file, so `a.read(5)` will fail.